# Concatenating object with attribute as String

Tags: python

I have the following function that takes in a response, a `CallableInterface` object,  and an attribute as a `String`.

```
def assert_response(response, api, expectedResponse):
    # api = self.Startup
    # expectedResponse = "ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED"
    eval(api + "." + expectedResponse)
```

The line seen above should evaluate to an attribute call as such:

```
self.Startup.ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

However, I am getting the following error because the value contained in `expectedResponse` is not being expanded.

```
AttributeError: 'CallableInterface' object has no attribute 'expectedResponse'
```

Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: I have read twice. I still can't figure out what you are asking. Maybe you should paste more code?

Comment: Reworded some parts for clarity. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access object attributes:

```
getattr(api, expectedResponse)
```

If the `api` is an object (i.e. `self.Startup`) which attribute is named as the value of `expectedResponse`, that should do it.

But before anything, make sure that contents of `expectedResponse` is actually what you think it is, by printing it beforehand.

Comment: I like this much better than OP's `eval` approach, but I suspect he'll get the same "has no attribute" error.